# Using xcodebuild to install the build target onto a locally-connected iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I'm trying to write a script that builds and installs my iOS project on one of my iOS devices.

I am not able to get `xcodebuild` to actually install the app on my iOS device:

`xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -scheme "MyScheme" -destination "platform=iOS,name=My iPhone" build install`

The project builds but the app doesn't appear on the device. Is this possible with `xcodebuild`?